# Store list of values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to store this list of values fetched from textfile into dictionary as key and value

```
filename = "parameter.txt"
f=open("parameter.txt")    
line=f.readlines()

for i in range (0,len(line)):    
    list1 = line[i].split("=")
    list1=[x.strip(' ') for x in list1]
    list2=list1[1].split(",")
    list2=[x.strip(' ') for x in list2]
    print list2
```

Comment: how file looks like ? can you provide us some input output examples ? and where is `list2` :) ?

Comment: give sample input, output to illustrate your need.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the input and output you'd like to see

Comment: What part of that are you stuck on, precisely? You don't seem to create a dictionary, identity an index or sub-index or attempt to place them into it; maybe start there?

Comment: What do you mean by index and sub-index? Are you referring to `key` and `value`? Which list you want make it as key and which one for value?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two lists into a dictionary by using zip function.

**General use**

```
list1 = ["key1","key2","key3"]
list2 = ["value1","value2","value3"]

print(dict(zip(list1,list2)))
```

Output:

```
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

*Note*:  If you're wondering why the code returned the lists in reverse order; it has to do with the implementation of zip and dict, but this will **not** effect the implementation of your code.  Order, regarding dictionaries, is not enforced anyway because, when calling a dictionary variable, you normally use newDict['key1'] and no reference to the index location is referenced.

**Your code specifically**

```
filename = "parameter.txt"
f=open("parameter.txt")    
line=f.readlines()

for i in range (0,len(line)):    
    list1 = line[i].split("=")
    list1=[x.strip(' ') for x in list1]
    list2=list1[1].split(",")
    list2=[x.strip(' ') for x in list2]
    print(dict(zip(list1,list2)))
```

Comment: same error :) when use open - don't forget close :) or prefer with open :)

Comment: The question is about how to combine two lists into a dictionary.  But I could add a note about best practice...  There is no talk about there even being an error.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want this:

```
fn = 'parameter.txt'
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    dict1 = {}
    for line in f:
        list1 = line.split('=')
        dict1[list1[0].strip(' ')] = list1[1].strip('\n')

print (dict1)
```

Comment: in your original example you are using error prone `f = open` and as usually :) forget closing it. try to stick to with open syntax to avoid such errors

Comment: did you try my code - it does split both key and value; i think it does the job you need, just not that bloated way

Comment: any way use  dict create line as example: dict1{} and then assign what ever is relevant to you with dict1[key]=value

Comment: How to do the same using indexing

Answer (score 0):

The following would work:

```
filename = "parameter.txt"
f=open("parameter.txt")    
line=f.readlines()

for i in range (0,len(line)):    
    list1 = line[i].split("=")
    list1=[x.strip(' ') for x in list1]
    list2=list1[1].split(",")
    list2=[x.strip(' ') for x in list2]
d = {l1:l2 for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)}
```

If you want to sort the dictionary by keys:

```
import collections
sorted_d_keys = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

If you want to sort the dictionary by values:

```
import operator
sorted_d_values = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```